# Leibniz convergence

Tags: sequences-and-series, discrete-mathematics, pi

I must demostrate the convergence of $pi$ in Leibniz series:
\begin{equation}
\sum_{i=1}^{+\infty}\frac{(-1)^i}{2i+1}
\end{equation}
I need to resolve it with this method $\displaystyle\lim_{x\to\infty}\frac{a_{n+1}{a_n}$.

I kown the solution, it is $\displaystyle\frac{\pi}{4}$, but i dont have the way.

Thanks

Comment: Can You share my the demostration ?

Comment: I think if you summarize from $i=0$ to $\infty$ then the result of the sum equal to $\frac{\pi}{4}$.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**HINT**

Recall that by Leibniz test for convergence of [alternating series](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Alternating_series_test) we need to check that

- $a_i\to 0$
- $|a_i|$ decreases monotonically